how to make inversion mutation using matlab code
if I have a chromosome =[1.01, 2.03, 4.06, 6.03, 0, 5.06, 4.12, 0, 3.03, -1, 1.12, 10.01, 4.05, 8.05, 3.07, 5.08, -1, 7.10, 8.01];
how can I separate it into segments using -1 gene
and -1 will be remain in the modified gene after mutation
I need to select 2 random indices inside any segment and make inversion mutation between those indices

idx = find(chromosome==-1); c1 = chromosome(1:idx-1); c2 = chromosome(idx+1:end);

@magnesium not a great idea; see this question on using == for comparison. Also, c1, c2 is hardly extendable (what if there are 50 chromosomes?). Shaimaa, please see [mre] and [edit] your post to contain the sample output of what you'd like to achieve and also what happens with multiple -1 values in your array.
